# First iPhone App View Position Problem

Tags: iphone, interface, view, builder

I am closely following the instructions given in the tutorial "Your First iPhone Application" on apple ADC.

In the interface builder, I have set up a button positioned on the top according to the Apple Interface Guidelines. It runs without trouble if I simulate the interface in IB. However, if I run the built app, I get what is shown [here](http://sz2.peterhi.com/tools/wrong.png).

If you look at the view clearly, you will see that the entire view has been shifted up. And the magnitude of the shift is exactly the height of the status bar. And that's why the there is blank space at the bottom of the window, which was white instead of red.

I have tried turning on the "Simulated Interface Elements", but that doesn't work either.
The problem persists on real devices as well.
However, using the "Simulate Interface" from IB looks fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Yun Tao

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the frame of your view?